# Displaying the 4th level of an array in CakePHP using relationship

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have table project, screenshot, sub_screenshot, and user 
 I want to achieve this kind of diagram. Its like getting the 4th level.

```
[Model]     
     Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Project] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                )
                            [Screenshot] = Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                       (
                                             [Screenshot] => Array 
                                                  (
                                                     [project_id] => 2
                                                     [id] => 1
                                                  )
                                             [SubScreenshot] = Array
                                                  (
                                                         [0] => Array 
                                                               (
                                                                  [id] = 1
                                                                  [project_id] = 2
                                                                  [screenshot_id] = 1
                                                               )
                                                         [1] => Array 
                                                               (
                                                                  [id] = 2
                                                                  [project_id] = 2
                                                                  [screenshot_id] = 1
                                                               )
                                                  )

                                       )
                                    [1] => Array
                                       (
                                             [Screenshot] => Array 
                                                  (
                                                     [project_id] => 3
                                                     [id] => 1
                                                  )
                                             [SubScreenshot] = Array
                                                  (
                                                         [0] => Array 
                                                               (
                                                                  [id] = 1
                                                                  [project_id] = 3
                                                                  [screenshot_id] = 1
                                                               )
                                                         [1] => Array 
                                                               (
                                                                  [id] = 2
                                                                  [project_id] = 3
                                                                  [screenshot_id] = 1
                                                               )
                                                         [2] => Array 
                                                              (
                                                                 [id] = 2
                                                                 [project_id] = 3
                                                                 [screenshot_id] = 1
                                                              )
                                                  )

                                       )
                              )
                          [User] => Array 
                             (
                                  [id] => 1
                             )
                      )
                )
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the containable behavior. I've had some questions about it lately too.  It would be much more efficient that setting recursive to 4 since you would only be including the models that you need.

Follow these instructions to setup the behavior on your models. http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable

Then, you should be able to perform a find and get the structure you want.

```
$this->Project->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            //put your conditions in here
        ),
        'contain' => array(
             'User',
             'Screenshot',
             'Screenshot.SubScreenshot'
             'Scrrenshot.SubScreenshot.User'
    )
);
```

There are a few ways to use the model syntax. You can add arrays to the contained models to add conditions and/or further depth.

Comment: I already tried the containable but it only display the {SubScreenshot} in the 3rd depth. I want to display it the {Screenshot array} so it would be {array(Project => array (Screenshot => array (SubScreenshot), User)} not {array(Project => array (Screenshot, SubScreenshot, User))}

Comment: It all depend on how your models are associated.  If screenshot hasMany subscreenshot then the containable behavior will do this.  I'll edit the post to get the user of the subscreenshot.

Comment: i already got it! i include var $actsAs = array('Containable'); in the Project model and include SubScreenshot in the screenshot model. Thanks!

Comment: Edit my answe to give user for subscreenshot.  Again, if the models are associated as you say, then this should output the array at the depth you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To give you some idea I suggest you to use the `afterFind()` callback

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1050/afterFind

After the find set the User wherever you want making another find with the User model.

I don't know if exists any configuration to modify the `$recursive` without a modification in the core.

EDIT

You can create a generic afterFind in AppModel when you can check if you have the $recursive=4 and copy the core functionality of the relationships and generate them.